# are access_token sensitive information to be shown public?

Tags: php, ajax, facebook, api, security

I was wondering if access tokens are sensitive information? I believe this is used in APIs? Also, access tokens are used to be stored in databases for future use?

Is it not good practice if it is used in `div attrivutes`, example : `<div id={access_token}>`?

Can someone shine some insights into this matter for me?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful not to take access tokens of your users out to the public, otherwise someone could use that access token to e.g. post from your users accounts (if this permission has been granted).
It is no problem to store tokens in a database. But they will expire after a while!

BTW: why would you take access tokens as div id's?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly, but I'm trying to integrate instgram's API. and to post they require this `curl -F 'access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN' \
    https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/likes` And I think, correct me if I'm wrong, that I'm using cURL in PHP and supposed to use `access_token` as the "form data"? So i'm trying to get the access_token with ajax to post it my page where it has the cURL script

Comment: You added Facebook as a tag, I don't know the Instagram API. But `curl -F` is the method to send HTTP POST data. Checkout http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.curl-setopt.php and have a look at `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` you don't need a html form to send a post request to the server!

Comment: I was able to do what I needed. Also, using sessions would just work